# Appium: How to scroll down drop down in an iOS app using Java

Tags: java, ios, drop-down-menu, scroll, appium

My objective is scroll down through the drop down until the state such as TN is visible to the user. This was possible in Appium when scrollTo() methods were working but they are deprecated in the current Appium build. I tried driver.swipe() but nothing happens. I am not well versed with iOS Predicates but tried using those too.

[image]

Alternatives tried so far but none worked:

**#1**

```
MobileElement element = wd.findElementByIosUIAutomation(
                ".tableViews()[0]" + ".scrollToElementWithPredicate(\"name CONTAINS 'TN'\")");
        element.tap(1, 1);
```

**#2:**

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) wd; HashMap <String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap <String, String>();
scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement)
wd.findElementByAccessibilityId("TN")).getId()); js.executeScript(
"mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

Comment: Have done this in Android but got no idea for IOS. Check this link for tests within the appium source which shows going to a text using scrolling. https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/ios/IOSScrollingSearchingTest.java

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried the `scrollByDriver()` yesterday & that did not work too. When it says **Slider** does it mean the text to be searched or is it something else?

Comment: Not sure about this but Slider in the test refers to the name of the inner element in the scrollable container. Have you tried the scrollByElement(). Are you able to find the options ie. state codes using the findElement by IOSUiAutomation.

Comment: **scrollByElement()** is the same as **scrollByDriver()**. The only difference is the use of extra variable for easier understanding or debugging. I tried butting name contains 'TN' but no scrolling happens. Here's my code: `MobileElement element = wd.findElementByIosUIAutomation(
    ".tableViews()[0]" + ".scrollToElementWithPredicate(\"name CONTAINS 'TN'\")");
  element.tap(1, 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out the solution but it was very difficult to find considering the lack of solutions:

```
String path = "UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().popover().tableViews()[0].cells()[\"TN\"]";
driver.executeScript(path + ".scrollToVisible();");

MobileElement state = driver.findElementByIosUIAutomation(path);
state.tap(1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
String uiAutoLocator = ".tableViews()[0].firstWithPredicate(\"name CONTAINS 'TN'\")";
driver.executeScript(uiAutoLocator + ".scrollToVisible();");
```

Make sure locator `uiAutoLocator` is resulting in an element.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I performed this for a simple UIListView and it works for that end since driver.swipe method is deprecated:

There you go

```
public static void scrollDownIos(IOSDriver<IOSElement> driver, double scrollPercentageStart, double scrollPercentageEnd) 
{
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int x = size.getWidth()/2;
    int starty = (int) (size.getHeight() * scrollPercentageStart);
    int endy = (int) (size.getHeight() * scrollPercentageEnd);
    (new TouchAction(driver)).press(PointOption.point(x, starty))
    .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(2000)))
    .moveTo(PointOption.point(x, endy))
    .release()
    .perform();
}
```